# Deploy azure resource in prebuilt resource group using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am having one resource group in my azure subscription name `"demoterraform"`
Now I would like to create one windows VM in this resource group, So I don't deploy new VM in existing resource group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [azurerm_resource_group data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/resource_group.html).

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "demo" {
  name = "demoterraform"
}
```

in the rest of the code you can refer to it with a similar expression `data.azurerm_resource_group.demo.id`.